# None values in numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, nonetype

I need to find out which indices in my numpy array are None.

```
In [1]: my_array
Out[1]: array([1, 1, 1, None, None, 3, 3, 3], dtype=object)
```

It is pretty easy to perform such thing with numbers:

```
In [2]: my_array == 1
Out[2]: array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

But I stuck at doing the same thing with None:

```
In [3]: my_array == None
/home/opt/anaconda/bin/ipython:1: FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.
Out[3]: False
```

Everyone is saying that the solution to avoid this warning is to use 'is' instead of '==', but it returns not what I'm expecting.

```
In [4]: my_array is None
Out[4]: False
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Comment: `np.flatnonzero(np.equal(my_array, None))` will give you the indices where `my_array` is `None`.

Comment: thanks a lot! just what I needed.